# Fish programming: Why are `bind` commands in config.fish not executed?

Tags: linux, shell, fish

At end of `/usr/share/fish/config.fish`, I have the following commands:

```
bind \e\[1\;5C forward-word
bind \e\[1\;5D backward-word
echo foo
```

Afterwards I run fish, it prints "foo". I then run `bind` to print a list of all binded key combinations, however there are no "forward-word" and "backward-word" entries in the output of `bind`.

Did I miss something?

Comment: What's the output of bind?  What's the "english" translation of what you're expecting to bind to?

Comment: He is trying to bind `meta-left` and `meta-right`. These bindings should already be in place though. So it might be your terminal emulator that is messing with you. Which one do you use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT: fish 3.0+ allows you to create key bindings during startup inside your `config.fish` or configuration snippets (`conf.d/*.fish`). See [fish-shell/pull/5195](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/5195)

---

Since those keybindings are already defined in [fish_default_key_bindings](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/share/functions/fish_default_key_bindings.fish#L71-74) I am guessing the problem lies with your terminal emulator and that it doesn't send the correct escape sequence.

You should also not edit the global config `/usr/share/fish/config.fish`.
Your custom config goes in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

If you want to specify your custom key bindings it should be done inside the function `fish_user_key_bindings`.

You can do this manually through editing: `~/.config/fish/functions/fish_user_key_bindings.fish`.

Or use the tools provided:

If the function does not exist you can do:

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
  bind \e\[1\;5C forward-word
  bind \e\[1\;5D backward-word
end
funcsave fish_user_key_bindings
```

Or if you already have the function:

```
funced fish_user_key_bindings
funcsave fish_user_key_bindings
```

The reason why you cannot specify these in your config is that they are reset at a later point, [here inside fish_default_key_bindings](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/share/functions/fish_default_key_bindings.fish#L4-5).

Comment: your solution works perfectly. However I still wonder why fish would not run `bind` commands in config.fish...

Answer (score 6):

Simply put this inside function named `fish_user_key_bindings` in your `config.fish`

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
  bind \e\[1\;5C forward-word
  bind \e\[1\;5D backward-word
end
```